# What's the difference between the @property decorator and @[property name].getter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, getter-setter

What is the difference between the @property decorator and the @[property name].getter decorator. From my understanding, they seem to be essentially the same except that @[property name].getter overrides the other, eg:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.__n = n

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.__n

    @n.getter
    def n(self):
        return self.__n + 3

obj = Class(5)
print(obj.n)
```

Is there any purposeful difference other than that?

Comment: No effective difference. A property has three optional fields: getter, setter and deleter. `@property` creates a property that already has a getter; but for completeness sake, all three fields are overridable (or more precisely, a copy of the original property can be created with any of the three fields replaced).

Comment: the complete explanation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: It's an alternative way of constructing a property object, almost like a builder pattern, alternatively, you could do something like `n = property(getn, setn, deln)`

Comment: You'd never want to do this, but the following also work: `property.getter(property(), func)` or more simply `property().getter(func)`, which is the decorator `property().getter`

Comment: (Un)fortunately `property` seems to be a very self consistent class, and there is no exciting caveat to write about here.